# The jquery accordion overlaps the content of my header

Tags: html, css, web, portfolio

I am using the jquery accordion source for my website and what happens when I scroll down is the accordion overlaps my header.

I haven't made any adjustments to the CSS code in the accordion class so I don't have much to show but I've read a lot of people complaining that the accordion source from jquery UI has this problem but I have not been able to find out what it is?

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
<script>
JQuery(document).ready(function(){
$("#accordion").accordion(); 
});
</script>

</a>
</div>
<nav class="nav"> 
    <div class="padded"> 
    <ul> 
        <li class="active"><a id="link1" class="nav-section1" href="#section1">About</a></li>
        <li><a id="link2" class="nav-section2" href="#section2">Design</a></li>
        <li><a id="link3" class="nav-section3" href="#section3">3D + Animation</a></li>
        <li><a id="link5" class="nav-section5" href="#section5">Video Production</a></li>
        <li><a id="link6" class="nav-section6" href="#section6">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="scrollTop"><a href="#"><span class="entypo-up-open"></span></a></li>         
    </ul>
    </div>   
 </nav>


<div class = "accordion">   
 <article> 
    <h1 id="section1">About</h1>
    <p>Farman Pirzada is this one dude who's pretty awesome and there's a lot you should learn about him because I love him</p>

    </p>
 </article>
```

and here's the CSS

```
 #accordion { 
 padding-left: 100px;
 }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb5Qq.jpg

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: We need to see the code, the accordion always works fine when i use it, so there must be a mistake in your code

Comment: my mistake for not putting up the code, but i put it above and hopefully this helps out now. Thanks!